# Is it possible to make this kind of label using apex charts with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

[image: apex charts label]

I've been tinkering with the options for some time now and managed to offset the the dataLabels, then using formater to add some custom text.

```
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        colors: ['primary'],
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontWeight: '400',
      },
      formatter: (value: number): string => `${Math.round(value)} %`,
      dropShadow: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    }
```

However I'm struggling with any way to get the labels text (for example the Up to 15 years) on the same position.
This is where I managed to get:

[image: What I managed]